# What is the significance of antinode at r=0 in the plot of radial wave functions of s-orbitals?

Tags: quantum-chemistry

[image]
Why should there be an antinode at r=0? 
I can comprehend the presence of node at r=0 for p,d,f orbitals; but I don't understand that of s-orbital. 
Is there any intuitive approach?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! We have a site policy for [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/141/7448) questions. Please edit your question to include your attempt at the problem, where you got stuck, and let us know where you're finding difficulty so we may best help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of : [2s orbital wavefunction has non-zero probability at r=0?(duplicate)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/174738/2s-orbital-wavefunction-has-non-zero-probability-at-r-0) from another site on the network (**physics.SE**). Interestingly, that question is also a duplicate.

Comment: @ANBENZENE please do research (at least a little!) on google before asking a query, it really helps.

Comment: [A nice little meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4708/491709) for other users in doubt

Comment: Ask yourself: what do ordinate and abscissa in the plots represent? Then follow the logical implications of a value y=0.